# Error when I am trying to open file in Ranorex Studio/C# file

Tags: c#, csproj, ranorex

I am trying to open a file but I am getting this error. I am trying in Ranorex Studio to execute a test suite, and when I am trying to open a test case file, it's throwing the below error:

[image]

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> ICShapCode.SharpDevelop.Util.ProcessRunnerException: No process running.

Comment: I know Ranorex.   Like any paid product, you would arguably be better off raising a ticket/searching Ranorex support than asking here.  Wishing you well

Comment: According to the exception, it might have something to do with the GIT addon or the AvalonEdit add-in. I would try to remove the add-ins and see if it helps.